# Как правильно пишется слово «воспитан(н)ый»?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, как пишется - с одной или двумя Н?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть четкое правило, которое указывает на то, одну или две буквы Н написать в слове «воспита[н]ый». Для этого необходимо определить его принадлежность к части речи и морфему, в которой находится орфограмма.

**Правильное написание**
Правилами русского языка определяется однозначное написание слова – с двумя буквами Н: воспита**нн**ый.

**Правило**
Орфограмма находится в суффиксе: *воспит* (корень) + *а* (суффикс) + *нн* (суффикс) + *ый* (окончание). Чтобы объяснить ее написание, определим часть речи и рассмотрим условия, которые сопутствуют выбору орфограммы:
**1.**  «Воспитанный» – в зависимости от контекста может быть отглагольным прилагательным или страдательным причастием прошедшего времени (на это указывает суффикс -НН-).
**2.**  Образовано от слова «воспитать».
**3.**  «Воспитать» является глаголом совершенного вида, у него нет приставки.

В отглагольных прилагательных и страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени пишется две буквы Н, если они образованы от глаголов совершенного вида, употребляемых без приставок.
Другие примеры на это правило: *брошенный камень* (от «бросить» — сов. вид.), *решенная задача* (от «решить» — сов. вид.).

Следует помнить, что особенность слова в том, что оно может быть отглагольным прилагательным и причастием, это зависит от смысла предложения. Впрочем, и в том, и в другом случае оно будет писаться с НН:
• отглагольное прилагательное несет значение постоянного признака: *Девочка показалась мне воспитанной, приличной;*
• причастие имеет значение действия, совершенного в прошлом: *Воспитанная в лучших традициях, она не ответила на выпад.*

**Примеры предложений**
***Воспитанный** Алеша Телятников отдалился еще шага на три к окну...* (Ф. М. Достоевский, «Бесы»);
*Это был мой отец в другом издании, иначе **воспитанный*** (А. Герцен, «Былое и думы»);
***Воспитанный** в строгих традициях, вице-канцлер любил холодок в отношениях* (Марк Алданов, «Заговор»).

[Как правильно пишется слово «воспитанный»?](https://uchipravila.ru/orfografiya/vospitannyy)

Comment: Просто на заметку, Александр: такой растянутый ответ сложно воспринимать. Я подправлю, если Вы не против.

Comment: Спасибо. Эти правки были жизненно необходимы - теперь гораздо лучше.

Comment: А зачем в полной форме различать причастия и прилагательные?Две НН пишется в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 3):

Слово ***воспитанный*** может быть причастием или прилагательным, обе формы указаны в словаре:

Причастие. **ВОСПИТАТЬ**,  **воспитанный;** -тан, -а, -о; св. 1. кого (кем, каким). Вырастить (ребёнка), воздействуя на его духовное и физическое развитие; 2. что. Привить, внушить кому-л. какие-л. чувства, развить навыки.

Прилагательное. **ВОСПИТАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -тан, -танна, -танно. Получивший хорошее воспитание, умеющий вести себя в обществе. В. юноша, ребёнок.

**В полной форме** в обоих случаях пишутся две  буквы НН, поэтому различать причастие и прилагательное **нет смысла:** различаются только краткие формы причастий (Н) и прилагательных (НН).

**По формальному правилу** Розенталя  выбор НН определяется тем, что глагол воспитать **совершенного вида** (что сделать). Сравнить: *купленный, брошенный*.

Comment: *Правила не только формулируются, но по возможности объясняется их смысл.* — у вас здесь нарушение грамматики. Союз "не только ... , но и" соединяет однородные члены предложения. Ну и "и" должно быть. Правильно: *Правила не только формулируются, но и по возможности объясняются.* Или: *Здесь не только формулируются правила, но и по возможности объясняется их смысл* (соединяет простые предложения).

Comment: Почему не исправили? Эта ошибка вас дискредитирует, она же в титулке, дальше даже не захотят читать :)

Comment: Вот этот источник: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.14